# What does an If statement followed by a semicolon instead of curly brackets mean in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was recently looking at some vp8 sample decoder code when I came upon this.

```
for(y=0; y<img->d_h >> (plane?1:0); y++) {
    int iLength = img->d_w >> (plane?1:0);
    iFrameCursor += iLength;

    if(fwrite(buf, 1, iLength, outfile)); //This semicolon
        buf += img->stride[plane];
}
```

Any idea what the if statement means?

Comment: This looks more like a mistake to me. The statement terminator should not be here as the next statement will run only once. Looks like a typo error.

Comment: like @James said, this statement does nothing; it's probably a typing error. A smart compiler will not even include that statement in the generated assembly

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer Agreed.  Especially because of the indent of the following line. From the man page: fread()  and  fwrite()  return the number of items successfully read or
       written (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error  occurs,  or
       the  end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or
       zero).

Comment: I was thinking pointer to pointer ...

Comment: @bitbucket: Agreed. The programmer might have tried something inside if() and afterwords forgot to remove the if() or maybe he took this snippet from the internet as if(fread())  is one of the finest ways of writing to file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The semicolon here is the same as if you had said `{ }`.  It is just an empty statement.

The following lines of code all do the same thing:

```
if(fwrite(buf, 1, iLength, outfile));

if(fwrite(buf, 1, iLength, outfile)) { }

fwrite(buf, 1, iLength, outfile);
```

### This is probably an error.

Comment: @Danny: Nobody said that it shouldn't. However, it's almost certainly not what the original code author intended; not only is it a completely silly thing to do, but look at the indentation on the next line.

Comment: it's either a bug or the author realized that the next statement is not conditional and created a quick fix (a forgot to fix it)

Comment: @Danny A program might compile and run without crashing, that does not mean it does what it was intended to do.

Comment: @yi_H: The "quick fix" is to remove the conditional.

Comment: @Danny: Here's my program to calculate the number "3": `int x = 1+1;` It compiles and runs fine, so it must be correct, right?

Comment: @Tomalak: that's a proper fix. `;` is just one extra character, you can't beat that

Comment: @yi_H: Yes you can. You can do it properly. Coding to the minimum number of keystrokes possible is stupid.

Comment: What @Etienne says is true. There's a difference between working and working correctly.

Comment: Unless you a perl-golf addict. What I wanted to say: it's not necessarily a bug.

Comment: @yi_H: in code golf, the goal isn't to type the fewest characters, but to end up with the fewest. removing the `if(` and `)` is much better golfing, and also not completely obfuscated.

Comment: It looks like the code must be doing something else too and someone removed that something in the if statement afterwords and forgot to remove that if()

Comment: you guys are way too serious. I would never write code like that, but that doesn't mean *nobody* would

Comment: `if(fwrite(buf, 1, iLength, outfile)) { ; }` too

Comment: @Martin:  It's a shame Stack Overflow filters out the `<blink>` tag ;-)  I think that would help accentuate the point even more

Answer (score 1):

```
if (<expr>) <statement>
```

usually the statement is a code block but it can be an empty one statement(`;`).

the code is equivalent to:

```
fwrite(buf, 1, iLength, outfile);
buf += img->stride[plane];
```

Answer (score 1):

If its a colon, it is used [instead of brackets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx). This probably seems like a mistake.